# Algorithm to break down a list of item into the minimum number of groups that can be used to represent it

Tags: c#, algorithm, lossless-compression

I'm sorry for the broad question, but I'm struggling on how to start with this one. I have a vague idea what I'm actually trying to do is something a compression algorithm does, but really I'm looking for someone to point me in the direction of a writeup I can use to base this off of.

Basically I have file. This file is made up of multiple lines. Each line is a comma separated list of items. I want to generate a new list of the minimum number of subsets of these list that can be used to build up the original file.

An example will probably illustrate this better, at its most basic if I have an input file of

```
A,B,C,D
E,B,C,D
F,B,C,D
G,B,C,H
A,I,J,D
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
9,5,6,7,2,3,4,1
```

my output should look like

```
A
B,C
D
E
F
G
I,J
1
2,3,4
5,6,7
8
9
```

as this is the minimum number of unique groups I need to build up the original list.

I'm pretty certain I'm describing the job of a compression algorithm (though what I'm doing this for isn't for compression) but I can't find any documentation for implementing something like this on a string array in C# as I am trying to - the best I can find is pre-built libraries for compressing/decompressing a byte array which isn't want I want. The closest I feel I've got is googling "Huffman coding", which seems along the right tracks for what I am attempting to do but to be honest I'm struggling to understand how to implement anything based off of what I am reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems straight-forward enough:

First try A, the first character seen.
See if it's always followed by the same character. Answer AB, and AI, so just [A].
Add [A] to the list. Remove all [A] from the input.

Try B (next character found). See if it's always followed by the same character. Answer BC always, so yes, now also see if C appears where it's not preceded by B, it doesn't, so add [BC] to the list. Remove all [BC] from the input.

And so on.

Comment: This seems feasible.. only problem is my question was a bit simplified. In reality the items will be names of objects instead of A/B/C etc.. so instead its Object1,Object2,SomethingB etc.. but I could perhaps break it down into an array of strings rather than char by char. But then I can't think how to handle seeking ahead into other lines without treating the boundaries between lines as if they are part of the sequence (i.e D/r/E shouldn't detect the same as D,E)

Comment: I ended up making some tweaks to this, but the rough idea worked. I split my document into a 2d array, I took the first non-null element and checked all other rows it exists on. I then look forward one element, and check that the same sequence existed on the rows I found in step one. I repeat this "check next element" process until it reduces the number of rows it applies to. Once i've found my "max" count that apply to all rows, I add the sequence to a seperate array and replace the sequence in all the rows it was found in with "null". Repeat until the source array is nothing but "null".

Answer (score 0):

So your reinventing [Lempel-Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78)?

The idea is that you make a dictionary (like what you already made somehow) by making a list of distances backward from the current position and a length to copy to the out stream.

LZ77 Pseudo code from wikipedia.

```
while input is not empty do
    prefix := longest prefix of input that begins in window
    
    if prefix exists then
        d := distance to start of prefix
        l := length of prefix
        c := char following prefix in input
    else
        d := 0
        l := 0
        c := first char of input
    end if
    
    output (d, l, c)
    
    discard l + 1 chars from front of window
    s := pop l + 1 chars from front of input
    append s to back of window
repeat
```

Following your input we note that 'A' is the first char and that there is no prefix, so
(0,0,'A') is written and 'A' is added to the prefix.

Next 'B' is not in the prefix so its added, (0,0,'B') and 'B' is added to the prefix, and so on until 'E' included.

The next is 'B', which already exists, the 'B' position in the prefix is -4, the following 'C' and 'D' are also in the input so length is 3, (-4,3,'F'), 'F' is the next in the input. This means that sometimes a char is repeated in the stream, you can avoid that if you don't need to represent \0 as a char and use it as a no added to the prefix.

Comment: Not quite I don't think, because this will build the "compression" up based on the first parts read in and then any sequences that match what's already been seen it'll discard/replace based on what it already has - using this algorithm I don't see how I'd generate my example output. Maybe I'm misunderstanding. I want smallest number of unique elements, not strictly compression.